# Is it possible to run giter8 templates from intellij?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, module, giter8

As a feedback from a g8 template that I've made, I've been asked whether it's possible to make it available directly inside intellij.

Is there any way to generate new modules from intellij using a g8 template, maybe through some g8 plugin integration? I've made some attempts unsuccessfully and can't find anything documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ doesn't currently support giter8 directly. If you would like to see it, please vote on [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-10898) on the IntelliJ Scala YouTrack.